# Appending an element at the end of a table row without jQuery? (using AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a normal HTML table and I need to append a button at the end of each row that will have a function attached to it.  I'm using AngularJS so I don't want to use jQuery to add it.  Is there any way to do this?  Every time I try to add a div inside the row, it just deletes it.

EDIT: added a fiddle of what the table looks like

https://jsfiddle.net/vgck08zn/

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">amount</th>
      <th scope="col">dob</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>$10.00</td>
      <td>03/02/2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>bob</td>
      <td>$2.00</td>
      <td>02/01/02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>will</td>
      <td>$200.00</td>
      <td>01/01/2003</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want a button that shows up only when you hover on a row, and the end of the row

Comment: May we see what you have tried so far so that we can offer some advice and suggestions. As written your post is far too broad for us to even begin providing an answer.

Comment: The only allowed content for `<tr>` elements is `<td>` or `<th>` elements. `<div>` elements are not allowed inside rows.

Comment: @Lex just added a fiddle of the example table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in items">
 {{item}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>
  This will show after each row (below of each start item), you can add your button here.
</div>
```

again, above code add content after each row and not at its end.

**Update:**

I have made for you an example using your table but with ng-repeat. https://jsfiddle.net/cimuca/tzaurgsy/

You can do it with ng-repeat, mouseenter, moouseleave. You have a full example in the jsfiddle above.

I have used mouseenter and mouseleave on the ng-repeat TR, when you enter or leave the row the button will show/hide. You have a click function for that button as well, clicked will show you in the console the item "row data" you just clicked.

You can use the mouseenter and leave on TD or any other element you may use in the tr. Example, if you use the ng-mouseover on a TD the div will show only when you hover(mouseenter) that TD.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was trying this but for some reason the new div didn't work inside the table.  I was using td's though instead of the divs like in your example

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
td{width:100px;}
th{font-weight:bold;}
button{width:100px;}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table border=1 style="border-collapse:collapse;border:0;text-align: left;" ng-if="items.length >0">

 <tr>
  <th> id </th>
  <th> name </th>
  <th> price </th>
  <th> quantity </th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-mouseover="item.show_action = true" ng-mouseleave="item.show_action = false">
  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.price}}</td>
  <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
  <td ng-show="item.show_action" style="border:none;">
      <button ng-click="removeItem(item)">X - Delete
      </button> 
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        $scope.items.push({
          id:(i+1) ,
          name:("item "+i), 
          price :(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)),
          show_action :false,
          quantity:(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))    
        });
     }       
    
    $scope.removeItem = function(item){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      if (item.id === $scope.items[i].id) {
          $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like it would work but I don't want the button to actually be part of the table.  I want the button kind of at the end of the row, overlaying the last column ONLY when i hover upon the row

Comment: you can put an ng-mouseover event on the <tr> and equate it to an ng-show on the <td> with the action button

Comment: @JackJohnson i updated it but kept it in the table. i think its mostly css at this point to achieve what you want.